# WinUI list control that allows for dynamic item size, reordering, and virtualization

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit, winui, variablesizedwrapgrid

I am trying to implement a document editor similar to Notion or Craft but in a WinUI/UWP application. Instead of using a "single-field" editor (like MS Word has), these apps show a vertical stack of content rows (so-called "blocks") that can contain text, media, link previews, LaTeX, etc. These rows can be rearranged with a `::` handle on the side:

[image: Notion UI recording]

So I've been looking for some list/stack control that:

- Recycles the row views that are not visible (i.e. "virtualization" in the XAML terminology).
- Allows to reorder rows by dragging and dropping them (single or multiple).
- Automatically adjusts row heights based on their content growing or shrinking in height (due to the user's input or because the app's window resized horizontally and wrapped some content).

Features I do *not* need: headers, columns, sorting, filtering. I have reviewed the following controls in WinUI 2.x and Windows Community Toolkit, but it looks like each of them lacks one or more of the required capabilities.

##### [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.listview)

It seems to be the go-to control for the lists with drag'n'drop, but it can't resize the items dynamically. Also, its dragging uses the whole item area while I need to make it available only with a `::` handle on the side.

##### [ItemsStackPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.itemsstackpanel)

A virtualization-supporting version of [StackPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel), but, as far as I understand, panels are supposed to be used for simple layouting of child items and not for presenting long lists based on a data source.

##### [VariableSizedWrapGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid)

This is the only list/grid control that officially declares the support of variable-sized items, but at the same time, it does not support virtualization. However, I found a [solution from 2013](https://windevgo.wordpress.com/2013/08/10/virtualize-the-variablesizedwrapgrid/) that is based on pre-calculating the content size for invisible elements.

##### [ItemsRepeater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.itemsrepeater)

A very basic control that does not provide virtualization on its own: "ItemsRepeater supports virtualization when attached to a host that supports virtualization."

##### [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid)

A rather heavy control from WCT that seems to be the only one to [dynamically resize cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/sizing_options) depending on their content. Unfortunately, it does not allow row reordering (only sorting), so I can't use it either.

---

Did I miss something? If not, I wonder which one would be the best to build upon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, a `ListView` **can** resize its items dynamically – one just needs to put a `StackPanel` inside a `ListViewItem` because a stack "pushes" its parent's size outwards. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33995285) says:

> Container controls like `Grid` and `RelativePanel` automatically scale to the full available size of their parent, while others like `StackPanel` only grow to the minimal size needed for their child elements.

Also, adding a `TextBox` inside a `ListViewItem` overrides the dragging behavior with text input behavior, but the list item is still draggable outside the text box. I can leave it like this or reduce the draggable area to the `::` handle by following [Arya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68189802/1014048).

Answer (score 1):

I have to say there is no control could fulfill all demands. In fact, the **::** is used to control darg the specified item, you could achieve similar behavior in ListView control.

The ListView allows you to easily reorder items inside a ListView by setting the `CanReorderItems` and `AllowDrop` properties to **True**.If you don’t want to allow the user to drag specific items, you could set the `CanDragItems` property to **True**, and add an event handler for the `DragItemsStarting` event. For the event handler, you can check any condition and then simply set the Cancel property of the event arguments to true if you want to cancel the dragging action. As follows:

Xaml code:

```
<ListView x:Name="TargetListView"              
                CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" AllowDrop="True"         DragItemsStarting="TargetListView_DragItemsStarting">

            <ListViewItem>
                <TextBlock x:Name="item1" Text="item1"/>
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem >
                <TextBlock x:Name="item2" Text="item2"/>
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>
                <TextBlock x:Name="item3" Text="item3"/>
            </ListViewItem>
          
  </ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
private void TargetListView_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = e.Items.Any(o =>
            {
                if (o is TextBlock t && t.Name.ToString() == "item2")
                    return true;

                return false;
            });
        }
```

As you can see, there are three textBlocks in ListView, the drag action of the textblock named item2 will be limited.

Comment: I added a bounty and then solved the problem on my own with some help from .NET Discord, so it goes to you! :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear your question has been solved. Wish you all the best.